# Thermocouple simulator circuit : isolation & voltage reference

Tags: simulation, opto-isolator, dac, isolation, thermocouple

I'm designing a multi-channel (6-10) thermocouple simulator.
For different reasons, all the outputs must be isolated to simulate completely the behaviour of the real-life thermocouple.

To do the task without breaking completely the bank (and also to avoid adressing 10 similar DACs that only have 4 I2C adresses available), I was thinking of using an opto-coupler and a PWM signal that I would then smooth out with a simple RC filter. Bandwidth is not the key here and a 100Hz "refresh" rate is more than enough.

Since the voltage range of a type-K thermocouple is roughly between -10 and 50mv, I tried to go with the lowest voltage source (a voltage reference in this case) to chop. In this case, a 500mV voltage reference (LT6650). Given the PWM resolution is high enough (16bit for general purpose timer on the STM32), that should give me enough resolution.

Then comes an op-amp in unity-gain/follower configuration for impedance matching purposes

The first questions that I have :

- Can I use the voltage reference (chopped by a NPN transistor) ? Do I need a follower between its output and the opto-coupler drain ?
- Same question with the opto-coupler, do I need another NPN transistor in-between ?

[image: Thermocouple simulator]

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: You need to specify some accuracy targets to have a sensible answer. At a first glance I would say this would be pretty terrible, in ripple, in accuracy and temperature stability and so on.  Single pole filter? Why use an instrumentation amplifier for a single-ended application? 500mV is a pretty high FS value for a T/C. I assume you will provide a temperature sensor per channel or one sensor and isothermal connection points.

Comment: 14 questions previously asked and several appear to have decent answers. Are you aware that this site relies on folk asking questions to formally accept the best answer (should it be good enough of course) and that process is described here: [Take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour). It'll take you two minutes to understand what is required and a few more minutes to go through previous questions you have received and formally accept answers that help you. You don't want other folk thinking you are mean do you?

Comment: @Andyaka I certainly wouldn't :-)
Will correct my errors right now.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany : I am aiming at +-5°C error range which is more or less +-200µV for a typeK.

When you say ripple would be terible, would that be the case even with heavy filtering?
What about the temperature stability while using a voltage reference (which supposedly has a good T° stability) ?

Comment: @VoltsAndNuts Hmm, you don't appear to have done anything despite saying *Will correct my errors right now*.

Comment: @Andyaka The deed is now done

Comment: Ok, I don’t expect you feel better for that but, well done.

Comment: Believe or not, I actually do!